# Thread/Runnable doesn't call run

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft

I am trying to make a little test Minecraft 2d version and I can't proceed any further since my thread won't call run(). I have indeed seen lots of tutorials where this works, even one of my own games uses this method and it works. I was basically copying off of that other game I made that worked.

```java
package com.bmc.minecraft2d;

import com.bmc.graphicsengine.Window;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Minecraft extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    private Window window;
    private Thread thread;
    private Graphics2D g2d;

    private void init(){
        window = new Window("Minecraft 1.17.1", 800, 600);
        thread = new Thread();
        thread.start();
    }

    public Minecraft(){
        init();
        System.out.println("Got past init.");
    }

    private void update(){

    }

    public void addImage(String file, int x, int y, Graphics g, int width, int height, boolean scaleImg) {
        Image img;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File(file));
            if(scaleImg) {
                Image scale = img.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
                g.drawImage(scale, x, y, this);
            } else {
                g.drawImage(img, x, y, this);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void render(){
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null){
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        addImage("../../assets/dirt.png",0,0,g,0,0, false);
    }

    public void run(){
        System.out.println("In the game loop.");
        while(true){
            update();
            render();
        }
    }

    public void stop() throws InterruptedException {
        thread.join();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Minecraft(); // Get out of having to use "static"
    }

}
```

I am using IntelliJ IDEA CE. May switch back to Eclipse some time in the future.

Comment: The thread does not automatically know which runnable to run. You need to pass the runnable in the constructor. thread = new Thread(this);

Comment: @Torben that works but gives me an error
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component must have a valid peer. It also says the error is coming from where my render() function is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, looks like I've answered my own question again. I figured out that I forgot to add the game to the JFrame (idk why i just like making games with jframes and plain java without libraries like glfw or lwjgl. i just like building my games from the ground up for some reason.)